# Are all Turing machines recognizable?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, semi-decidability

Is the language of the set of *descriptions* of all Turing machines recognizable?  I'm thinking not, but I can't quite define why.

A language is Turing-recognizable if some Turing machine recognizes it.  So I guess I'm wondering if the language L of all Turing machine descriptions is Turing-recognizable.

Comment: This may answer your question :http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/37818/language-consisting-of-all-turing-machine-encodings

Comment: I think you are confusing Turing machines with their domain.

Comment: How do you distinguish a Turing Machine from a non-Turing Machine?

Comment: I just simplified the question, I'm wondering about the language of all Turing machine descriptions, is that recognizable?

Comment: This seems to be the same question as http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/37818/9550 but we can't close as a dupe because that one doesn't have an answer.

Comment: What is a Turing Machine Description (for the purpose of your question) ?

Comment: A Turing machine description is a string description of how the machine operates.  So think of some C program code string identifying how the compiled code behaves.

Comment: Well, if that is what you consider a description (some people might disagree), what would you say about recognizability of C programs? By the way, you should state that explicitly in your question if you want to have it reopened, since it would make it different from [the other one](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/37818/9550). Understanding why might teach you something important.